# correct drift of interval javascript

Tags: javascript, math, timer, drift

This can be a Javascript or a Math problem.

I am trying to make an interval that doesn't drift away from the system's clock. I need also to be able to change the interval at runtime, thus most cron libraries don't serve the purpose. The time scale I am speaking about is 10-5000 milliseconds. My concern was not micro-precision timing, but having zero-drift away in the long run.

I made a simple solution that sets an interval, and the callback function compares how many times the interval has run, and divides it by all the time that the "interval" has been running. The total time/ iterations will give the exact, overall drift that the iteration has incurred into. This ensures that no drift is accumulated. Measuring the time from last run of the iteration would not guarantee that no drift is being accumulated. My example plays a midi note every "accurate" interval".

test app:

```
  var targetInterval=(60000/120)/4;
  var lastDrift=0;

  var jazz = require('jazz-midi');
  var midi = new jazz.MIDI();

  var name = midi.MidiOutOpen(0);
  if(name){
    console.log('Default MIDI-Out port:', name);
  } else {
    console.log('Cannot open default MIDI-Out port!');
  }

  var absoluteInterval=0;
  var absoluteDrift=0;
  var timeAnchor=0;
  var iterations=0;


  function a(){
    var now=new Date();
    var elapsed=now-timeAnchor;
    console.log("tick");
    iterations++;
    absoluteInterval=(elapsed/iterations);
    absoluteDrift=targetInterval-absoluteInterval;
    setTimeout(function() {
      a();
    }, targetInterval+absoluteDrift);
    console.log("  Interval:"+absoluteInterval);
    console.log("  drift:"+absoluteDrift);

    midi.MidiOut(0x99,(Math.random()*60)+40,100);
  }
  function changeRate(to){
    targetInterval=to;
    iterations=0;
    timeAnchor=new Date();
  }
  function start(){
    timeAnchor=new Date();
    a();
  }
  start();
```

My problem now is that when the rate is changed, drift recovery is slow. Indeed, the drift recovery is infinite because targetInterval-(elapsed/iterations); always approaches zero, but it will never get to zero; and thus the extra added to the interval is just exactly less than enough. I tried multiplying, but this results in exaggerated recovery intervals, and the same math principle is still there avoiding total recovery anyway. Should I try to quantize (ceil) the recovery rate, or is there a solution for this that makes more mathematical sense?

Comment: Have you looked I to the web audio API? I'm pretty sure that has a mechanism for stable music timing

Comment: `setInterval()` has no long-run drift AFAIK. It's just that each individual callback is not guaranteed due to runtime constraints of JavaScript, since it's single-threaded and likely something else is executing at the time.

Comment: @PatrickHund thanks! Hopefully I can get away without adding dependencies. I forgot to mention I am using Node

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, specially in node. But sadly it doesn't allow for changes in the rate

Comment: @Joaquin the way you change the rate is you store a reference to the output of `let ref = setInterval(...);` and then when you need to change it, make sure to `clearInterval(ref)` before setting it to a new one. This way you can take advantage of JavaScript's built-in drift mitigation while having a runtime-configurable rate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks! I tried that, but there is a cumulative drift in comparison to the value of Date()

Comment: I would try to avoid using `Date()` as it won't give you as accurate a representation as [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time). `Date()` isn't based directly off system time, but rather a less reliable source that's platform dependent.